# Security issues by using public-read object for s3 images

Tags: amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

In our application user upload images which are stored in s3. these images will be displayed on website. So I made the image object as public read. And using the s3 object URL (http://bucket.s3.aws-region.amazonaws.com) to display image. what can be the security issues by doing this

Comment: If you made the object public, then the image is public. Are you okay with that? Or do you want better control over who can access images? What is your actual desire?

Comment: I'm afraid that any one can see the folder structure of my s3 bucket from the image url, is there any to may map s3 url with api gateway url.                                   or is it ok to expose whole bucket information in public. Thanks for reply

Comment: That choice is totally up to _you_. Do you _want_ the content of whole bucket to be public? Or would you rather control access to the content so that only specific people have access to specific content? If so, please edit your question to provide more details of what you would _actually_ like to achieve.